# How to create Unit Tests with dependencies

Tags: c#, unit-testing, selenium, automation

First off I want you to understand that I know in 99.9% of situation a unit test with dependencies is not wanted, however I think this is that 0.1%.

The situation is I am working on a framework for selenium based automation tests for a website. I have methods to perform different actions ie. logIntoSite(usersname, pass), createEvent(eventName, eventTime), deleteEvent(eventName).

And here is the issue the function obviously need the site to be running correctly, and a failure of the test could be an issue on my side OR it identified a site issue. When there is a site issue their may be a number of the tests we would not want to run as the core function of the site it depends on is not working.

The example I am working on right now is, I have a function to create a event, I also have a function to delete an event.

If there is a site issue where an event cannot be created the first test fails correctly, but so does the delete event function even thought there may not anything wrong with that feature.

This is not an issue with having each test be self sustaining as the delete function does not depend on the create "function" to run, the delete function does create an event to delete itself.

So I left with 2 failures, when what I want is 1 failure and one test skipped because of the failure. By itself that doesn't sound bad, but as the tests grow we end of with more and more, ie. editEventName, updateEventTime... etc. now I have 4 failures... I hope you can see my issue.

I am currently using visual studio with TestTools.UnitTesting;

Comment: These aren't unit tests then. They're integration tests. Integration tests will test a whole system behavior rather than specific chunks (though there may be multiple integration tests that cover different functionality, they will be much larger in scope than unit tests).

Comment: _... in 99.9% of situation a unit test with dependencies is not wanted_ - this is so not true. I want have tests which will test whole "pipe-line" of my application (end to end tests) - Then I will have freedom to refactor things, adapt new approaches which can be discovered later after I start working on a software. But problem that this kind of tests are very slow (UI, web services, file systems).

Comment: @Fabio Then it's not a unit test. A unit test will test a specific piece of code in isolation. You would set up *all* the dependencies directly within the test, and the test would be completely isolated from the results of any other tests. If you have tests that are spanning multiple pieces of functionality and are dependent on each other, then those are integration tests.

Comment: Yes, they often uses unit testing tools. But when communicating with other developers on websites like Stack Overflow, it's important to use the correct terminology so that you aren't misunderstood.

Comment: @mason, you are technically correct but what I am dealing with is a bit of a grey area between the two test types. I develop the framework that is used for the Integration tests, but the functions themselves need to be tested in isolation. So my tests are closer in nature to a unit test in nature, but in functionality look more like integration tests as they have no access to the underline code.

Comment: The main thing is there is no test tools for integration tests (in practice what I am coding IS the testing tool). So one is still left with the underlying issue, I have to use the unit test library in which I am looking for a way to have dependence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a solution for this in Visual Studio. It's called an [Ordered test](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182631.aspx). You create it by right-clicking on the test project and selecting Add > Ordered Test.

The dialog that opens is intuitive. You can add tests to a list and order them, and determine whether test execution for the group should stop with a single failure. You can add one test to multiple groups. You can add a group of tests to another group.

That would allow you to begin a test group with a test to verify that the site loads, and stop execution of the following tests if that one fails. You can a collection of test groups where each group will run even if a different group fails, but within a smaller group a failure stops execution. So testing of one feature could stop if a prerequisite test fails, but testing for other features continues.

I've never used this, never seen it used, and I didn't know it existed. But it might be just what you're looking for. To me it would only be useful in a scenario like this where the tests might take longer and it could be beneficial to skip some if some precondition determines that a lot of them are guaranteed to fail.

Comment: This might be my best option from your description. I will play around with it today and see how well it works out.

Answer (score 1):

You could create properties in your test class of `bool eventCanBeCreated`, and then `if (eventCanBeCreated)`, `Assert.Inconclusive("The dependent test " + testName + "failed.  Skipping this test");`.

This would look like:

```
public class TestClass
{
    public bool eventCanBeCreated = true;

    [TestMethod]
    public void CreateEvent()
    {         
        // Your code

        // Before Assert.Fail():
        eventCanBeCreated = false;
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void DeleteEvent()
    {
        if (!eventCanBeCreated)
            Assert.Inconclusive("The dependent test " + testName + "failed.  Skipping this test");

        // Your code
    }
}
```

It may also be worthwhile from there to attempt to enforce that `CreateEvent()` is attempted before `DeleteEvent()`, as although this is bad practice, it would guarantee in this case that you don't waste time running tests that you don't need to.

Comment: That is a possibility. 
Only concern is growing a large ugly list of variables as the number of tests and dependencies grow, but it would work.

Comment: That is a risk.  If you have that many dependencies though I would suggest instead seeing if you really need to test the exact same feature that many times.  That is, instead of using the normal test framework, with a separate test Edit/Update/etc, create a single event test and then log to a console or an external file what all is working and not.  That would significantly reduce your test run time, and you could integrate much better logic if it were a real program.

Comment: If this was the integration test itself that would be best, but these are tests for the functions themselves that others use to create test scripts for the integration tests. 

ie. They have a test case that is to have someone register for the event. So they use this function to create the event, and then script booking someone into it.

Comment: This is kind of a hybrid of unit testing and integration testing. It is a unit test for the functions I make, but because these functions span a number of actions that are taken on the site itself it's behavior is more in line with integration.

Comment: @ZeroScifer Alright, sounds good.  You probably know your product better than I do :P